# "This PC" window opens automatically after login

Tags: windows-10, boot, autorun

Every time I boot my laptop "This PC" window opens.

1. I downloaded [Autoruns](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Autoruns.zip) unchecked all the entries on the Logon
   tab.
2. I checked in Settings - Personalization - Start - 'Choose which
   folders appear on start!', 'File Explorer' was turned off
3. I checked in Settings - Apps - Startup, Explorer is not listed
   there.
4. I checked in Settings - Accounts - Sign-in options, 'Use my sign-in
   info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or
   restart' toggle  was turned off
5. In regedit navigated `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
   In the right-side panel, change the value of `PersistBrowsers` to `0`.
6. In regedit navigated `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and changed the value of `Userinit` to : `C:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe`

Rebooted but still "This PC" window keeps opening on startup.

My Windows specifications are as below.

```
Edition:    Windows 10 Pro
Version:    21H2
Installed:  ‎19/‎09/‎2021
OS build:   19044.2006
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4180.0
```

I would appreciate any recommendations that would fix this problem.

Comment: What fixes have you tried exactly? Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: Does this behavior happen when you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: yes it did open in safe mode

Comment: Have you tried resetting your file Explorer options? What I suspect is something is opening file Explorer and your options are set to open “this pc”